# Disagreement on Convergence of Integral between Mathematica and WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, convergence

I am trying to do the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+\cos(t))\cosh(t)dt$. Doing this on Mathematica gives me that the integral is equal to 0. However, doing this on WolframAlpha gives me that the integral does not converge. Why are the results different?

Comment: I get it doesn't converge in Mathematica.

Comment: Me too  in 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: I see, I'm doing this in 11.3. I will try updating and seeing what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Also, not a converging answer in `12.0.0 for Linux x86`

Comment: It is obviously divergent

Comment: In *version 13.0.1 *  this `Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Cosh[t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]` yields `Integrate::idiv: Integral of Cosh[t]+Cos[t] Cosh[t] does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}.`  while `Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Cosh[t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]`  yields `0` and this is acceptable.

Comment: $\lim_{\delta \to \infty} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta}(1+\cos(t))\cosh(t) dt =0$ i.e. this is convergent in a very special sense.

Comment: How can that be true but it's not convergent? @Artes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug specific to version 11.3 of Mathematica.  The correct answer is non-convergence.  Indeed since the integrand is even, we can compute the integral as

```
Limit[2 Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Cosh[t], {t, 0, b}], b -> \[Infinity]]
(* \[Infinity] *)
```

which evaluates correctly even in version 11.3.  BTW, this disproves the comment that the limit of the integral over symmetric domains is zero.  That could only happen for an odd function such as the following one

```
Limit[Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Sinh[t], {t, -b, b}], b -> \[Infinity]]
(* 0 *)

Limit[Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Sinh[t], {t, a, b}], {a, b} -> {-\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
(* Indeterminate *)

Integrate[(1 + Cos[t]) Sinh[t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
(* returns unevaluated with non-convergence message *)
```